# Reproducing results by: use Shell;

Tags: linux, perl, shell

I am trying to reproduce the same results three different ways, but am having trouble figuring out how to get it working when using "use Shell;" (method 2a below), any help?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# v5.10.1 / linux
use strict;
use warnings;
use Shell;

# method 1 start
my $result = `df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom|none' | awk '{ print \$5 "\t" \$1}'`;
print $result . "\n";
# end of method 1

# I would like to try to reproduce the above but by using "use Shell", even if the above is already somehow using such anyway?!
# method 2a start
my $result2 = df ("-H");  # use powers of 1000 not 1024 # human readable
print $result2 . "\n"; # I can only get it working up to here 
# end 2a

# 2b) 
# or use regexs on df -H's output
my @linesofoutput= $result2=~/(.*?)\n/g; # needs checking to see if I'm getting the lines right with this?!

 foreach my $temp(@linesofoutput){

if (($temp  =~ /^Filesystem/)||($temp  =~ /^tmpfs/)||($temp  =~ /^cdrom/)||($temp  =~ /^none/)){ 
    # do nothing for lines starting with Filesystem, tmpfs or cdrom or none
     # print "Do not show:  $temp\n";
}else{
            #print "$temp\n";  # lines wanted
                 my  @words = split(/\s/, $temp);           # make an array out of each line, splitting on any whitespace character: space, tab, newline, etc
                 @words = grep(!/^$/, @words);            # remove empty elements.  check this(not starting with, ending with)???

                 print "$words[4]". "\t"."$words[0]"."\n";          # filesystem entries are in index0, size index1, used index2, avail 3...
                 # be careful of /path/name of file or folder... because of the gaps, and so they could be made up of multi indexs
            }
 }
 # end of method 2b
```

Comment: Did you read the PerlDoc for `Shell`? It explicitly states, that it should not be used in production programs.

Comment: Yes, saw that, am just exploring things perl, it is not for any production program... am trying to learn by building up several ways of doing the same thing... It's a place to start for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, method 2a) should pipe the output of `df -H` into the `grep` and that should pipe to `awk`. In short: You want to do the complete redirection stuff of method 1 which is done by the implicitly started shell in perl.

The `Shell` package will **NOT** help you here. The sole purpose of that package is, that you can call *one* command easily. So `df("-H")` works, but that all of it.

That is no great loss if you think about it: All you need is the output of `df`. The rest is parsing and processing that output - something which *should* be done in perl itself. So method 2b is the better way anyway - if you polish it a little bit like this:

```
my @lines = df("-H");
shift @lines;   # get rid of "Filesystem..."
for( @lines ){
    next if /^tmpfs|cdrom|none/;
    my @words = split('\s+', $_);
    print $words[4], "\t", $words[0], "\n";
}
```

I may also propose a method 3: Replace the call to "df -H" with something from perl. Here are some CPAN modules which use the `statfs(2)` or `statvfs(2)` system call:

- https://metacpan.org/pod/Filesys::Df
- https://metacpan.org/pod/Filesys::DfPortable
- https://metacpan.org/pod/Filesys::DiskSpace

Comment: Thanks, your understand was right on A.H... I will try to add those ones to my methods and thanks for the polish too, could I have your thoughts though on why it may be or is better to use pure perl as it were?

Comment: First: efficiency: `awk` and `grep` are programs which must be loaded, which in turn load dynamic libraries and, must read input, produce output which must be transferred between programs... a lot of overhead for no benefit. Second: Perl is very good at processing and transforming data. So IF you use perl anyway, the use it to the full extend possible and feasible. Don't introduce new tools if the already used tool can do the job.